# GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch doesn't show login screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-data-api

I'm using objective c gdata client and I have a problem with GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch. It was working for me (shows UI, returns callbacks), but now it shows just empty white screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So, I have found a solution. It seems to be a wrong build configuration for gdata static library. So I have unset GTM_INCLUDE_OAUTH2 to not include gtm auth controllers to static library and then add this classes directly to application. gtm auth can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.xib in your project